# bash bang - full line except last arg

Tags: bash

How do I do a bang command to repeat last line, but with changed last argument?

Comment: http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/02/unix-quick-tip-repeat-the-last-entered-command-with-bang-bang/

Comment: I guess there are other uses than just ease of typing, but <Up> <Home> "sudo " <Enter> is as many key presses as "sudo !!" <Enter> (even fewer if one counts the <Shift> to get !), and more general. Similar combinations also nullifies other uses of the !! operator, in my experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
!!:0- new_last_argument
```

See [this article](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/) for an overview.

Comment: I couldn't tell from the article whether that was substituting or appending new_last_argument for old_last_argument.  At the bottom of the link there's a cheat sheet that spells it out.  Good reference!